# Template Debugging: which entry is actually slow?

Tags: templates, speed

I'm trying to see why it takes almost 3-4 seconds for my template render. I enabled template debugging. Looking at the output, I have computed 0.7 seconds between two steps in the templating process:

[image]

I'm not exactly sure what it means. Did the HTML Minification take .7 seconds? Or was it Mo' Variables?

Also, should I be concerned about memory usage when trying to figure out bottlenecks in my templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule in reading debugging logs, output statements that are designed to allow developers to profile the speed of their web application are always placed at the start of methods. Not the end.
So in your case it is the HTML minification process that is taking the 0.7 secs to execute. Which depending on the complexity of your HTML is not too bad.

To speed things up, I would consider using caching for this page.
[CE Cache](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-cache) by Causing Effect is a fantastic caching solution for EE giving you great control - especially the neat cache breaking feature.

In regard to the memory usage of the PHP instance, this should also be taken into account. The more memory you use for a single PHP instance, the longer it will take for the server to process. Using too much memory can also result in RAM swapping when the system is under high load. Something you definitely want to avoid especially considering the cheapness of adding extra RAM to your server (especially if it's in the cloud).